# How can I generate HTML and CSS from shapes and text drawn/inserted on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, interactive

What I would like to do essentially is to create HTML and CSS *backwards* from "manually" inputted shapes and text on a webpage.

What this would look like is manually creating and/or drawing shapes on a webpage (like one would in Powerpoint), with the output being an HTML page with CSS properties.

As an example, if I "draw" a red rectangle on the page, the output would be a web page [very roughly] looking something like this:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<style>
  #rect1 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
  }
</style>
<div id = 'rect1'></div>
```

Eventually I would like to add more complex features like filling in text inside shapes, as well as implementing interactive features which would add javascript to the outputted .html.  But before that–and in light of this question's broadness–I would like to figure out what a possible starting point is and what key words are involved in such a project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're looking for this: https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics). With it you can essentially draw vectors (in this case, on a website) and CSS can be applied to it, and JavaScript can alter it.

Comment: You *should* provide at least one example or at least some links.